# How do I reference a nested type in SpEL?

Tags: spring, spring-el

Given a class containing an enum:

```
public class MyClass {
    public enum NestedEnum {        
        value1(1),
        value2(2);

        private int code;

        private NestedEnum(int code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public int getCode() {
            return code;
        }
    }
}
```

how do I reference NestedEnum?  This:

```
#{T(MyClass.NestedEnum).value1.getCode()}
```

results in the exception:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E:(pos 0): Type cannot be found 'namespace.MyClass.NestedEnum'
```

This:

```
#{T(T(MyClass).NestedEnum).value1.getCode()}
```

results in the exception:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 3): Unexpected token.  Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lparen(()'
```

I cannot think of any other good options to try.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to separate the enum using a `$` sign:

```
#{T(MyClass$NestedEnum).value1.getCode()}
```

Comment: Would it be better to specify the `Type`->`NestedEnum` change in your answer, instead? Oftentimes 'wrong' code in questions should be left alone, so that the fix in an answer can be more obvious.

Comment: This would have been a solution too, but I assume it would have impair the understandability of the answer. I also assume, it was a copy&paste error of the questioner.Neverteheless, thanks for your hint.